# Adding name to previously published pre print in new journal

Tags: publications, journals, authorship

Can we add a coauthor to a previously published preprint and submit it to a peer-reviewed journal? I know we can publish the pre print in many journals but how about adding name?

Please note that the mentioned preprint is available online.

Comment: You should publish a paper in only one journal, publishing the same paper in another journal is not good.

Comment: It is totally wrong. Pre print is not journal!  most journals will happily consider, review and publish papers that have already been published as preprints. This can be the case if the work has changed substantially since its first publication or even if the definitive version is virtually identical to the preprint version.

Comment: There must be some terminology confusion here, at least for me. It sounds like you have uploaded a preprint of your manuscript, perhaps multiple versions, to multiple preprint distributors/websites. But it has not yet been peer reviewed, accepted for publication, and published by a journal. Is that right?

Comment: My pre print is published. I uploaded the same to a journal and explained that this was published as a pre print. They mentioned no problem .Now it needs revision after peer review of that journal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you publish a preprint with a certain list of authors, and then publish the "same" paper with different authors, it would look like you have been careless in publishing the pre-print, without giving proper credit to all the co-authors and/or without obtaining consent for publication from all your co-authors.

Ask the (to be added) co-authors if they want to appear in the pre-prints (and please provide a reasonable explanation why they were not in the coauthors list in first place), then if they answer yes you should update the pre-prints as well, to be fair and consistent (the exact same work, even if presented in different media and formats, should have the exact same authors list).